# Forcing file to download is not working

Tags: php, html, download

I am trying to download the file when user click on the link.The file is on some other website and I am passing the url of the file e.g.- xyz.com/filename.mp3.

```
echo "<a href=/direct_download.php?file=$link[$j]><img border='0' src='images/dl.gif' ></a>";
```

And here is my download file script.

```
<?php

$file_name = $_GET['file'];
//$files = rawurldecode($file_name);
echo $file_name;


if(is_file($file_name)) {
echo $file_name;

    if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) { ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off'); }


    switch(strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_name, '.'), 1))) {
        case 'pdf': $mime = 'application/pdf'; break;
        case 'zip': $mime = 'application/zip'; break;
        case 'jpeg':
        case 'jpg': $mime = 'image/jpg'; break;
    case 'mp3': $mime = 'audio/mpeg';break;
        default: $mime = 'application/force-download';
    }
    header('Pragma: public');   
    header('Expires: 0');       
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate ('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime ($file_name)).' GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: private',false);
    header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file_name).'"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file_name));    
    header('Connection: close');
    readfile($file_name);       
    exit();

}
?>
```

Comment: comment out echo $file_name; to avoid headers being sent to the browser before your header declarations are made.

Comment: nothing happens just the text is removed from the browser

Comment: Good call, @KaiQing. I also just now noticed it's exiting after readfile... I've never done that before but I wonder if-- hmmm... Now I have to check. Curiosity. ;)

Comment: I tried everything but its not working. Please just take any mp3 link from the web and tell me how this will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my guess is you are not including the directory.

```
$file_name = $_GET['file'];

$directory = 'set me up'; // directory for files

if(is_file($directory.$file_name)) {

$file_parts = pathinfo($directory.$file_name);

    if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) { ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off'); }


    switch($file_parts['extension']) {
        case 'pdf': $mime = 'application/pdf'; break;
        case 'zip': $mime = 'application/zip'; break;
        case 'jpeg':
        case 'jpg': $mime = 'image/jpg'; break;
    case 'mp3': $mime = 'audio/mpeg';break;
        default: $mime = 'application/force-download';
    }

$size = filesize($directory.$filename) ;
header("Content-Type: application/force-download; name=\"". $file_parts['basename'] ."\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ". $size ."");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"". $file_parts['basename'] ."\"");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
echo (readfile($directory.$file_name));
}
```

Comment: `$file_name` is not exactly somesong.mp3. Its is the whole path including teh directory like somewebsite/music/song.mp3. Why dont you get a link of the file and try yourself.

Comment: not really a good idea including full path in url as it will open you up to hack attacks. where is link btw. give an exact example of link.

Comment: you need relative path not absolute path.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `Content-Type` like so:

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
```

EDIT: although I still stay use `application/octet-stream` as the content type, please give this a try:

```
<?php
/**
 * Make sure that the VERY FIRST THING IN THE DOCUMENT IS <?php
 * There can't be any spaces or anything else before it, because if
 * there is then header information has already started to be sent
 * back.
 */

/**
 * Avoid warnings, notices, etc by check $_GET's value first:
 */
$file_name = ($_GET && isset($_GET['file'])) ? $_GET['file'] : FALSE;
//$files = rawurldecode($file_name);

/**
 * As soon as you "echo" something, headers are sent back to the
 * browser, the same way adding space(s) before the opening <?php
 * tag will. Once headers are sent, they can't be modified or you
 * will receive an error.
 */
//echo $file_name;


if(is_file($file_name)) {
  /**
   * See above for info on headers.
   */
  //echo $file_name;

  if (ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) {
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
  }
  switch(strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_name, '.'), 1))) {
    case 'pdf': $mime = 'application/pdf'; break;
    case 'zip': $mime = 'application/zip'; break;
    case 'jpeg':
    case 'jpg': $mime = 'image/jpg'; break;
    case 'mp3': $mime = 'audio/mpeg';break;
    /**
     * Although this works sometimes, I've had better luck with just
     * setting the content type to "application/octet-stream"
     * for anything that needs to be "forced" as a download.
     */
    // default: $mime = 'application/force-download';
    default: $mime = 'application/octet-stream';
  }
  header('Pragma: public');   
  header('Expires: 0');       
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
  header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate ('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($file_name)).' GMT');
  header('Cache-Control: private',false);
  header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file_name).'"');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file_name));    
  header('Connection: close');
  readfile($file_name);       
  exit();
}
?>
```

EDIT (again):

Also, please be advised that this:

```
echo "<a href=/direct_download.php?file=$link[$j]><img border='0' src='images/dl.gif' ></a>";
```

is almost definitely going to mess things up. Try it like this instead:

```
echo '<a href="/direct_download.php?file=' . $link[$j] . '"><img border="0" src="images/dl.gif" /></a>';
```

Comment: @mjosh: please see the above edits, and be sure that no whitespace or anything else at all exists before the opening `<?php` tag. Also, what @KaiQing said: don't `echo` anything.

Comment: not working ..why don't you try this code on some link and tell me if its working for you

Comment: I have tried it and it worked like a charm. I won't post it in one of my public servers however... It's certainly nothing personal (so please don't misinterpret this) but the reason I won't publicly use this code is because the code in and of itself is not sanitized and is therefore, in my opinion, insecure. But it *does* work on my local computer.

Comment: Something else worth mentioning is the fact that you don't have any quotes surrounding the link location (href) inside `echo "<a href=/direct_download.php?file=$link[$j]><img border='0' src='images/dl.gif' ></a>";` -- in fact, have you tried access the link directly (instead of clicking on the link)? That could very well be a contributing factor... Adding this to solution. for further explanation.

Comment: I tried accessing the link directly but its is opening inside my browser inside quicktime player.

Comment: Oh! Cool. Sounds like `Content-Type: application/force-download` is doing what it should be doing then. Problem solved..?

Comment: @mjosh wait-- you said it's opening inside quicktime player...? What kind of file are you trying it with? If it's a pdf, zip, or jp(e)g, then the content type is not being set as `application/force-download`. Can you provide the link for it?